# count and sum in case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, trino

What is the difference below if I use case instead of sum? I believe I would get the same output?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN salary > 100000 THEN 1 END) AS Total

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN salary > 100000 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Total
```

Thanks!

Comment: Count counts both ones and zeros

Comment: but in my example above doesn't the END or ELSE NULL make the case only count the specified value as 1?

Comment: Both count queries will raise "Null values eliminated in set function" warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three are equivalent.  All of them count the number of rows that meet the particular condition (`salary > 100000`).  All return `0`/`1` and would not return `NULL` values for the column.

From a performance perspective, all should be equivalent as well.  I have a personal preference for the first version.  I consider the third to be unnecessarily verbose because `else NULL` is the default for a `case` expression.

Answer (score 4):

Per the other answer, all forms are equivalent. There also a couple of other form that are more compact and achieve the same result:

```sql
count_if(salary > 100000)

count(if(salary > 100000, 1))
```

However, the idiomatic and more general way to do this in [Trino](https://trino.io/) ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) is:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE salary > 100000) AS Total
FROM ...
```

See the [documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html?#filtering-during-aggregation) for more details about filtered aggregations.

All other forms except for the one based on `SUM` should, per the SQL specification, raise a warning to indicate that null values have been eliminated. This behavior is not yet implemented in Trino, but will be added at some point in the future.